# Collapse one cell consist of multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a table, some of its cells have multiple lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Collapse</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            first line<br>
            second line<br>
            third line<br>
            fourth line<br>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

We can see a cell has four lines, what I want is when my mouse point at "Cell", I can collapse this, it will look like:

[image]

Also, if I want to expand this cell, just need to click on the "Cell".

I suppose I need javascript code to do this, and I want to insert the code into the html file.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you already tried something to do this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with javascript, so no, I haven't tried anything.